# Simulate pure virtual functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, virtual-functions

Pure virtual functions are seen in languages like c++, and offer a way to enforce implementation of a function in a subclass.

For instance:

```
class AbstractBaseClass
{
    virtual void speak() = 0;
}

class Subclass
{
    virtual void speak() override // implementation must exist 
    { 
        std::cout << "I am a subclass"; 
    }
}
```

What's the best way to simulate pure virtual functions in a language like Javascript?

A possible solution might be to throw an exception in the base class function if the call has reached this part of the prototype chain:

```
class BaseClass // ES6
{
    speak() { throw "Implementation of abstract method not found" }
}
```

Is there perhaps a better solution?

Comment: JavaScript is quite different from languages like C++ or Java, and trying to make it behave as if it weren't is generally a lost cause.

Comment: you might want to look into typescript or coffeescript for this kind of thing

Comment: Read about FlowType and Interfaces

Answer (score 1):

You can use TypeScript & then transpile to JavaScript (with ts, babel...). It will be statically checked by ts & not during runtime !

Here is an interface, an abstract & finally the class implementation.

```
interface IExample {
     method(param: any): any;
}

abstract class AExample implements IExample {
     abstract method(param: any): any;
}

class Example extends AExample {
     method(param: any): any {
          console.log('hello');
     }
}
```